# Сместить div с помощью css

Tags: html, css

Есть div. Ширина и высота задаются по размеру текста входящего в него.
Нужно подвинуть его ровно на половину от его ширины влево, и ровно на половину от его высоты вверх.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробую с помощью margin. Но это не верно.

```
.text-marker-class{
    margin-left: -50% !important;
    width: auto !important;
    height: auto !important;
    font-size: 9px  !important; 
    color: #414141;;
    background-color: #fcf8da;
    border: 2px solid #41575a;
    padding-top: 1px;
    padding-left: 2px;
    padding-right: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 1px;

}
```

Можно ли средствами css это сделать?

Comment: прописываете родительскому блоку ***display: flex; align-items: center;  justify-content: center;***, удаляете для **text-marker-class** ***margin***

Comment: Я не могу это сделать. Родительский блок это карта.  Там свой css и свои законы.

Comment: К слову, padding можно сократить до `padding: 1px 2px;`

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME Спасибо, сократил

Answer (score 1):

Почему так трудно выложить полностью код, чтобы можно было пощупать и показать на Вашем же примере, что нужно сделать?

Задайте для этого блока свойство `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);`